# Selenium : Two Buttons with same class name in a form

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have two buttons with same name " btn wb-btn-default " with two diffrent actions " Checkout " and " Order more " .

how to click on the Check out button.

[image]

Comment: Give them different id so you distinguish them

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ? Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a xpath with matching text value. For example:

```
//button_ngcontent[text() = 'Checkout']
```

Or you can loop through them & click on one matching the text. An example in python:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('wb-btn-default')
for button in button:
    if button.text == 'Checkout':
        button.click()
        break;
```

PS: You might have to tweak these example